# Is a question about research level practices appropriated to this community?

Tags: discussion

this is my first post here (at this community, although I know Kaveh from CS).

Since this is related to CS and Research I would be very much interested as an undergraduate and researcher assistant to ask a question related to research practice. This is not about a particular cs method or theory, however related to cs and research.

Is this off topic? Can I get up votes for agreement and down votes for disagreement if this is appropriated or not and if not comments on where I could ask this?

Thanks.

Comment: The best thing is to look through the tags for similar questions: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-practice

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your suggestion. Also, I would like to create this as an CW question but it seems I am not able to. Its definitely not a 'normal question type'.

Comment: sorry for being unclear: there is already a tag `research-practice`, so some questions about research-practice are appropriate. Then the best thing to do is to look at the existing questions, see if your question seems to fit and act appropriately. As for CW, if you really want it to be CW, after writing the question you should flag it for moderator attention saying you want this to be CW. However have a look at our [CW policy](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/759/the-new-community-wiki-policy)

Comment: If your questions is about a research related issue in *theoretical* computer science, then it can be on-topic, otherwise it is not. General questions about research practice should be on [academia.se], only questions essentially about *theoretical* computer science are on topic on cstheory.

Comment: thanks that answers my question!